# What happens when reset() is called by a unique_ptr twice?

Tags: c++, c++11

I have the following program where I call mc.reset() twice. I thought this would give me an error but this works without errors.

```
#include <iostream> 
#include <csignal> 
#include <memory>  // for unique pointer
using namespace std; 

std::unique_ptr<int> mc;

void signal_handler( int signal_num ) { 
    cout << "The interrupt signal is (" << signal_num << "). \n"; 

    mc.reset();
    mc.reset();

    // terminate program   
    exit(signal_num);   
} 

int main () {
    mc.reset (new int); 
    *mc = 5;

    // Press Control + c to raise SIGINT
    signal (SIGINT, signal_handler);

    while(true) 
        cout << "Hello..." << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

I used valgrind to check for memory leaks and found none:

```
==5467== 
==5467== HEAP SUMMARY:
==5467==     in use at exit: 0 bytes in 0 blocks
==5467==   total heap usage: 3 allocs, 3 frees, 73,732 bytes allocated
==5467== 
==5467== All heap blocks were freed -- no leaks are possible
==5467== 
==5467== For counts of detected and suppressed errors, rerun with: -v
==5467== ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors from 0 contexts (suppressed: 0 from 0)
```

What is actually happening when reset is called? Why am I able to call it twice without any problems?

Comment: Have you checked a [reference](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset)?

Comment: Signal handlers are very constrained as to what they can do reliably.  I'm pretty sure I/O is not allowed.  (I know this is just a small example program, but if someone did _Monkey C++, Monkey Doo-doo_ programming, they may form a misunderstanding.)

Comment: @Eljay What do you mean by I/O is not allowed? I ran the program and it works, are you saying it's bad style?

Comment: Even if the code is invalid you often shouldn't expect an error since many things in C++ exhibit undefined behavior which means that anything can happen, including your program appearing to work fine.

Comment: @AlexanderZhang I see, thanks for clarifying. I looked at this reference when I wrote this program (http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/csignal/signal/) and it does not mention that I/O is not allowed in a signal handler. Can you recommend any resources about signal handling which will explain details like this?

Comment: @RAR https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/program/signal discusses the limitations on signal handlers. They are very extensive. In particular, almost all standard library functions are forbidden, including both `operator<<(std::ostream)` and `std::unique_ptr::reset`. Until C++17, referring to `std::cout` or your `mc` object would also have been undefined behaviour - signals weren't allowed to access static variables unless they were atomic or volatile!

Answer (score 5):

See [the reference of reset()](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/unique_ptr/reset):

> 1. Saves a copy of the current pointer `old_ptr = current_ptr`
> 2. Overwrites the current pointer with the argument `current_ptr = ptr`
> 3. If the old pointer was non-empty, deletes the previously managed object `if(old_ptr) get_deleter()(old_ptr)`.

So calling `reset()` a second time on a `unique_ptr` does nothing, since the old pointer is then empty. And the new pointer (also empty) is the same as the old pointer.